# Correcting duplicate names in array

Tags: c#, beginner, algorithm, file

I have an array of file names. For example:

```
string[] files= { "one.zip", "two.txt", "one.zip", "three.txt", "three.txt", "one.zip" };
```

And I've developed the following method to correct duplicate names. What the method does is just change duplicate names. I am just adding incremented value for the next duplicated value. For example, my developed method `ChangingDuplicateNames(string[] files)`correct the previous array to:

```
string[] files= { "one.zip", "two.txt", "one1.zip", "three.txt", "three1.txt", "one2.zip"};
```

And implementation of `ChangingDuplicateNames(string[] files)` is:

```
private string[] ChangingDuplicateNames(string[] files)
{
    //Creating a dicitonary to store duplicated values. "Key" of dictionary        
    //is duplicated name, "Value" of dictionary is number to add for name
    Dictionary<string, int> duplicateNames = files.GroupBy(x => x)
        .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
        .ToDictionary(grouped => grouped.Key, grouped => 0);

    if (duplicateNames.Count == 0)
        return files;

    int namesLength = files.Length;
    string actualName = string.Empty;
    for (int indexArray = 0; indexArray < namesLength; indexArray++)
    {
        int incrementedValue;
        bool isDuplicate = duplicateNames.TryGetValue(files[indexArray], 
            out incrementedValue);
        if (isDuplicate)
        {
           actualName = files[indexArray];
           if (incrementedValue == 0)
              files[indexArray] = files[indexArray];
           else
           {
               //Adding increment to the mext duplicate name
               string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path
                    .GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[indexArray]);
               string fileExtension = Path
                   .GetExtension(files[indexArray]);
               files[indexArray] = fileNameWithoutExtension + 
                   "(" + incrementedValue + ")" + fileExtension;
           }
           duplicateNames[actualName] = ++incrementedValue;
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

And my question is: Is it possible to improve this algorithm? I mean could be this code smaller?

Maybe I should not iterate through the all array of names, but I cannot figure out how I can change names in `files` without iterating through all array. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick and easy way would be to use a [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) and check the return of the [`Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) method. If it returns `false` you will know that you need to create a new filename. So let's start by extracting the creation  of the filename like so

```
private string CreateFileName(string original, ref int counter)
{
    counter += 1;
    string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(original) + "(" + counter + ")";
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(original);
    return fileNameWithoutExtension + fileExtension;
}
```

Next we iterate over all of the items of the array and try to add it to the `HashSet<T>`. If we can't add it, we create the new filename and try to add it again until we succeed.

```
private string[] ChangingDuplicateNames(string[] files)
{
    var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var currentFile = file;
        int counter = 0;
        while (!hashSet.Add(currentFile))
        {
            currentFile = CreateFileName(file, ref counter);
        }
    }

    return hashSet.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: And fixed.......

Comment: sorry, that I gave simplified conditions of task, but I cannot apply your HashSet<string> to my HashSet<FileContent>. I always get result such as `""two(1).zip, two(1)(2).zip"`. Be very kind to revise my conditions again.

Comment: Heslacher, please see my another question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162593/correcting-duplicate-names-in-generic-array

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> files.GroupBy(x => x)
> ```

File names are case insensitive so your `GroupBy` should use the `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

---

Alternatively if you like LINQ you can *compress* the entire function into this expression:

```
var result =
    files
        .Select(f => new
        {
            Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f),
            Ext = Path.GetExtension(f)
        })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        .Select(g => g.Select((x, i) => $"{(i > 0 ? x.Name + i : x.Name)}{x.Ext}"))
        .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: It looks really great! Upvoted. Could you clarify where is incremention happened?

Comment: @StepUp the `Select` extension passes you the current item (here the `x`) and its index (here the `i`) that you can use to append to the name if it's greater then 0.

Comment: sorry, that I gave simplified conditions of task, but I cannot apply your HashSet<string> to my HashSet<FileContent>. I always get result such as `""two(1).zip, two(1)(2).zip"`. Be very kind to revise my conditions again.

Comment: "File names are case insensitive" on certain file systems, I.e NTFS without the FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS flag. Maybe you should pass a flag to the function so it knows whether they are insensitive or not.

Comment: @Peilonrayz are there really systems with case sensitive file names? this is worse then SharePoint :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just sort and do it on the fly
I think it will be more efficient than HashSet and sorted is a nicer presentation.

```
//test
foreach (string s in RenameFiles(new List<string>() { "one.zip", "two.txt", "one.zip", "three.txt", "three.txt", "one.zip" }))
         Debug.WriteLine(s);
//end test

public static IEnumerable<string> RenameFiles(List<string> files)
{
    string lastFile = null;
    int curIndex = 1;

    foreach (string s in files.OrderBy(x => x))
    {
        if(lastFile == null)
        {
            lastFile = s;
            yield return s;
        }
        else if (string.Compare(s, lastFile, true) == 0)
        {
            string name = $"{System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s)}({curIndex}){System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s)}";
            curIndex++;
            yield return name;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return s;
            curIndex = 1;
            lastFile = s;
        }
    }
}
```