# Correcting duplicate names in generic array - follow up

Tags: c#, beginner, algorithm, file

Follow Up question of : [Correcting duplicate names in array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162577/correcting-duplicate-names-in-array)

I have an array of file names. For example:

```
FileContent[] files =
{
    new FileContent() {Content = threeItems, Name = "one.zip" },
    new FileContent() {Content = fiveItems, Name = "one.zip" },
    new FileContent() {Content = sevenItems, Name = "one.zip" },
    new FileContent() {Content = threeItems, Name = "two.zip" },
    new FileContent() {Content = fiveItems, Name = "two.zip" },
    new FileContent() {Content = sevenItems, Name = "two.zip" },
};
```

Model:

```
public sealed class FileContent
{
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I've developed the following method to correct duplicate names. What the method does is just change duplicate names. I am just adding incremented value for the next duplicated value. For example, my developed method `ChangingDuplicateNames(string[] files)`correct the previous array to:

```
FileContent[] files =
{
    new FileContent() {Content = threeItems, Name = "one.zip" },
    new FileContent() {Content = fiveItems, Name = "one(1).zip" },
    new FileContent() {Content = sevenItems, Name = "one(2).zip" },
    new FileContent() {Content = threeItems, Name = "two.zip" },
    new FileContent() {Content = fiveItems, Name = "two(1).zip" },
    new FileContent() {Content = sevenItems, Name = "two(2).zip" },
};
```

And implementation of `ChangingDuplicateNames(FileContent[] files)` is:

```
private FileContent[] ChangingDuplicateNames(FileContent[] files)
{
    //Creating a dicitonary to store duplicated values. "Key" of dictionary        
    //is duplicated name, "Value" of dictionary is number to add for name
    Dictionary<string, int> duplicateNames = files.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
            .ToDictionary(grouped => grouped.Key, grouped => 0);

    if (duplicateNames.Count == 0)
       return files;

    int namesLength = files.Length;
    string actualName = string.Empty;
    for (int indexArray = 0; indexArray < namesLength; indexArray++)
    {
        int value;
        bool isDuplicate = duplicateNames
           .TryGetValue(files[indexArray].Name, out value);
        if (isDuplicate)
        {
           actualName = files[indexArray].Name;
           if (value == 0)
              files[indexArray].Name = files[indexArray].Name;
           else
           {
              //Adding increment to the mext duplicate name
              string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path
                  .GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[indexArray].Name);
              string fileExtension = Path
                  .GetExtension(files[indexArray].Name);
              files[indexArray].Name = fileNameWithoutExtension + "(" + value + ")"
+ fileExtension;
           }
           duplicateNames[actualName] = ++value;
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

And my question is: Is it possible to improve this algorithm? I mean could be this code smaller?

Maybe I should not iterate through the all array of names, but I cannot figure out how I can change names in `files` without iterating through all array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `files[indexArray].Name = files[indexArray].Name;` - really? (Then, I'd prefer `current` or `name` over `currentName` over `actualName`. Rather than assigning a descriptively named (conceptual) const (`isDuplicate`), I'd define a predicate…) Don't know about `improve … smaller`, but why iterate the names twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we are dealing now with objects, we need to create a copy of each `FileContent` to achieve the same result like in your previous question.

Instead of having `var currentFile = file` where `file` had been a string, we now use `var currentFile = new FileContent() { Content = file.Content, Name = file.Name };`.

In addition, we are using the `HashSet<T>` only for look up and return an `IEnumerable<FileContent>` instead of an array.

```
private IEnumerable<FileContent> ChangingDuplicateNames(FileContent[] files)
{
    var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var currentFile = new FileContent() { Content = file.Content, Name = file.Name };
        int counter = 0;
        while (!hashSet.Add(currentFile.Name))
        {
            currentFile.Name = CreateFileName(file.Name, ref counter);
        }
        yield return currentFile;
    }
}
```

and call it like so

```
FileContent[] result = ChangingDuplicateNames(files).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why do we use `yield` here?

Comment: Because we don't want to have a second hashset on which we call `ToArray()` later on. If you have an `IEqualityComparer<FileContent>` we could use a `HashSet<FileContent>` and then we could change the method back to returning `FileContent[]` by calling `hashSet.ToArray()`.

Comment: 1. Why do you prefer return type `IEnumerable<FileContent>` not `FileContent[]` of method `ChangingDuplicateNames(...)`?

2. Why don't you prefer return type `IEnumerable<FileContent>` not `FileContent[]` in  `ChangingDuplicateNames(...)` as a parameter?

Comment: 1. Its easier and cleaner this waym (IMO) 2. I guess you mean passing as a parameter, which isn't a problem. Just change `FileContent[]` to `IEnumerable<FileContent>`

Answer (score 3):

> Edit:
> I ran the original code, the answer and my solution here over 2400 records. I didn't find any significant differences in perf, but more rigorous profiling  should be done if the number of records is magnitudes larger. My improvements are based on the following observations:
>
> - You do a lot of work to make a unique name. Unless that format is required, I would go with appending a Guid to those duplicates or something. It is simply less code that I have to write.
> - You have a lot of variables capturing intermediate state: `duplicateNames` `namesLength` `actualName` `incrementedValue` `isDuplicate` `fileNameWithoutExtension` `fileExtension` `indexArray`.  If we could eliminate those, the code would be easier to read. I ended up with `uniqueNames` and i
> - I like that you remove duplicates in place in the original files list.
> - Another goal of mine was to see if I could reduce the amount of nesting of code.

Assuming we want to keep the original list in the same order, I use a `HashSet` to store unique names. Assuming we only care about making names unique, I create those using GUIDs. Here the code:

```cs
private static FileContent[] ChangingDuplicateNamesIII(FileContent[] files)
        {
            var uniqueNames = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (uniqueNames.Contains(files[i].Name))
                {
                    // Duplicate
                    files[i].Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[i].Name)
                        + "_"
                        + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                        + Path.GetExtension(files[i].Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    uniqueNames.Add(files[i].Name);
                }
            }
            return files;
        }

    }
```

Given the following input array:

```
FileContent[] filesSmall =
            {

                new FileContent() {Content = "1", Name = "one.zip" },
                new FileContent() {Content = "2", Name = "one.zip" },
                new FileContent() {Content = "3", Name = "two.zip" },
                new FileContent() {Content = "4", Name = "two.zip" },
                new FileContent() {Content = "5", Name = "two.zip" },
                new FileContent() {Content = "6", Name = "one.zip" },
                new FileContent() {Content = "7", Name = "one.zip" },
                new FileContent() {Content = "8", Name = "one.zip" },
                new FileContent() {Content = "9", Name = "two.zip" },
                new FileContent() {Content = "10", Name = "two.zip" },
                new FileContent() {Content = "11", Name = "two.zip" },
            };
```

It produces the following output, with the first column representing the Content  (in our simple case a string).

[image: Output from ChangingDuplicateNamesIII]

Comment: I don't think attaching a GUID instead of a counter is such a good idea. Besides the review part is missing. This is virtually the same code as in the other answer. With this solution there is also no way of knowing that a file with a certain name exists multiple times because of the long meainingless GUID. On top of that there is no review.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This was my first time answering a question here and I could have done a better job. I'm looking forward to learning from others and doing  better, because that  is a significant part of what code reviews should be about.  Post edited with more details.   
My solution is very different from the answer, although I did read and run it - no negations, no IEnumerable with a yield, no counter variable, no method to create a file name, no foreach and, last but not least, I replace duplicate names inline in the original array. I hope this helps and appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Downvote undone ;-)